# Deployment with Capistrano

Tags: php, capistrano

I am trying to get into PHP app deployment with Capistrano. I have two config files that I need to be "edited" depending on where I deploy it. It's basic stuff like database name and root url (Codeigniter). Can I make Capistrano edit specified automatically? Let's say I want to edit the following in the file /system/config/edit.php:

```
$test = '';
// edit to
$test = 'Hello World';
```

Thanks,
Max

Comment: If there is a find string solution I would prefer it to a find line solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Unix is knowledge isn't quite up to scratch so I can't quite get the syntax perfect for what you want. However, Capistrano allows you to directly use the Unix command-line by invoking [:run_method](http://www.capify.org/index.php/Variables#basic) within your configs.

The Capistrano code might look something like the following:

```
run "grep -R --files-with-matches '$test = "";' /system/config/ | xargs perl -pi~ -e 's/\$test = "";/$test = "Hello World";/'"
```

I would check up on that find and replace function working as expected before implementing it live though.

If you need any more help, I'd recommend checking out the [Capistrano Handbook](http://github.com/leehambley/capistrano-handbook), it should answer most of your questions.

Answer (score 5):

What I generally do in this kind of situation *(even though I don't use Capistrano)* is to have several config files commited to source control.

For instance :

- `config.php` for development machines

  - this file is the one that's always used by the application
- `config.testing.php`
- `config.staging.php`
- `config.production.php`

And when deploying the application to the server, I just have to copy the file corresponding to the current environment to "`config.php`" -- as this one is the one that's always used by the application.

It means that I have to do a file copy during the build process, yes, but :

- it means there is no need for any search and replace, that can break
- it also means every config files are commited to SVN *(or whatever source control software you are using)*

If your configuration files become too complex, and duplicate lots of stuff, you can think about having one "default" config file, that's always included, and sub-config files that only define what depends on the environment.

What that, what I said before still stands : just include the "default" file at the begining of each other.